# Percentage of the total revenue

Tags: sql, oracle

I have category, Sub-category and Revenue.

```
Category    Sub-Category    Revenue     Percentage
---------------------------------------------------------
Books       Text Books      5000        (5000/14000)*100
            Comics Books    6000
            Horror Books    3000
```

Now my question is, how to achieve like this using SQL?

I need percentage wrt to total sales for that category.

Comment: Please provide What You have tried.

Comment: Dear Friend You Should also provide some sample code which you tried and because of some reason not working

Comment: @RJ1990:use `((sum(revenue) over (partition by category)) /revenue)*100 as percentage` in your select statement

Answer (score 6):

Oracle has [RATIO_TO_REPORT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions142.htm#SQLRF00691) analytic function, which computes the ratio of a value to the sum of a set of values.

```
select category, subcategory, revenue,
       round((ratio_to_report(revenue) over (partition by category) * 100),2) as percentage
from mytable;
```

Output:

```
CATEGORY  SUBCATEGORY  REVENUE  PERCENTAGE
-----------------------------------------
books     text         5000     35.71
books     horror       3000     21.43
books     comics       6000     42.86
```

Sample fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a857b/3)

Answer (score 2):

You can use an [analytical SUM function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions001.htm#autoId17):

```
select
  Category,
  SubCategory,
  Revenue,
  Revenue * 100 / sum(Revenue) over (partition by Category) as Percentage
from
  yourTable
;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subselect to get the overall revenue and use it in the calculations.

```
SELECT category, sub-category, revenue, 
((revenue / 
  SELECT sum(inne.revenue)
  FROM table inne
  WHERE inne.category = oute.category) * 100) AS percentage
FROM table oute
```

Comment: That only returns the desired result if there is only one category in that table. If there are multiple ("Books", "DVDs", ...) this won't work.

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer: +1 for different answer :),but its less optimised than others

Comment: @GauravSoni You are right, my approach is not the most optimized.